# Help with IDA pro please -- functions made are not Xref'ing to the caller

Tags: ida, disassembly, firmware

I am reversing some Motorola 9s12 (68hc12) code and using IDA pro.
I am having the strangest issue.

The code makes a call to a function:

```
ROM:B300                 call    $BFF7, #$FE
```

when I go to the function and make it a function
with the <kbd>P</kbd> key (auto analysis does not pick this 
up as a function)

ROM:BFF7 sub_BFF7:
ROM:BFF7                 ldab    #$46 ; 'F'
ROM:BFF9                 stab    byte_3C
ROM:BFFB                 clrb
ROM:BFFC                 clra
ROM:BFFD                 rtc

IDA fails to insert the function name 
(in this case `sub_BFF7`) into  the original call.

What am I missing here?

The original call still reads:

```
ROM:B300 sub_B300:
ROM:B300                 call    $BFF7, #$FE
```

Somehow the XREF'ing is not working.

Answer (score -1):

probably it's some bug in 68k processor module of IDA. What you can do is create the script which will find all call instructions and create xrefs properly.